# Not completely horizontal lines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art

[image]I made horizontal-supposed lines using line tool and holding Shift key. But it seems like my lines are not completely horizontal. I am attaching the capture of what I see.[image]

This becomes more obvious when I zoom in.

Answer (score 1):

Check the lines in **Outline Mode** by choosing `View > Outline`. If they are straight there, then the issue is with the pixel display of the monitor you are using and its inability to accurately place pixels for the preview.